# How do I convert this piece of XML into a javascript collection?

Tags: javascript, xml, collections

I'd like to convert XML that looks like this:

```
<products>
   <product>
     <Name>Bill</Name>
     <ID>1</ID>
     <Age>19</Age>
   </product>
   <product>
     <Name>Jim</Name>
     <ID>2</ID>
     <Age>23</Age>
   </product>
   <product>
     <Name>Kathy</Name>
     <ID>3</ID>
     <Age>53</Age>
   </product>
</products>
```

INTO THIS FORMAT: Name, ID, Age in a collection

Like the following:

```
collection = [
'Bill-1-19',
'Jim-2-23',
'Kathy-3-53',
];
```

I think the best way to do this is with an XSLT stylesheet that outputs it right?  I could really use some help, I've been trying to figure this out for hours now.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // for IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","after.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xml=xhttp.responseXML;

var products = xml.getElementsByTagName("products");
var arr = [];
for (var key in products){
    var stringVal = "";
    var nodes = products[key].childNodes;
    for (var ele in nodes){  
        if(nodes[ele]){
           stringVal = stringVal + nodes[ele];
        }
    }
    arr.push(stringVal);
}
console.log(arr);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that _really_ what you want... stuff the name, id and age into a single string?  If you're going to using in Javascript wouldn't it be better as a collection of objects with fields for each value?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use xml? If flexible I would use JSON instead since it converts more easily to JavaScript objects

Comment: I could convert the XML to JSON with an online tool if you want.  Basically I just need to get the XML data into that collection format by ANY means.

Answer (score 0):

not had this tested it but this should work IMO.
Just iterate the XML listing and build a string

var products = xml.getElementsByTagName("products");
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in products){
        var stringVal = "";
        var nodes = products[key].childNodes;
        for (var ele in nodes){  
            if(nodes[ele]){
               stringVal = stringVal + nodes[ele];
            }
        }
        arr.push(stringVal);
    }
    console.log(arr);

Comment: This is javascript right? How can I get this code to execute?

Comment: Add script tag in the html page